# MySQL: SELECT and UPDATE in one statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have:** Select some set of pairs. The first column is the id of row in `table`, the second is the new value which should be assigned to that row.

```
-- the first query
CREATE TABLE tmp;
SELECT row_id, new_value
FROM [not essential tables and joins];  //PSEUDOCODE

-- another queries
FOR EACH tmp //PSEUDOCODE
  UPDATE table SET value = new_value WHERE id = row_id;

-- QUESTION: CAN I MERGE SELECT AND UPDATE IN ONE QUERY? 
-- I want avoid creating temporary table.
```

**Problem:** Iteration through table (as in example above) decrease clearness and speed of code.

**Question:** *How to do the same in single query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for update the table join with other table (Not sure though). You can do something like

```
UPDATE tmp a 
    JOIN sometable b ON a.col = b.col 
    AND a.id = b.row_id 
SET a.value = b.new_value
```